# JHipster 4.1.1 and Highchart (Angular2)

Tags: angular, highcharts, jhipster

I am trying to integrate the Highchart library into my JHipster 4.1.1 project.
I follow the steps of this web

https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-highcharts

1-I run the following command at the root of the project

```
npm install angular2-highcharts --save
```

2 - I add the following in my module file:

```
import { ChartModule } from 'angular2-highcharts';

@NgModule({
imports: [
BrowserModule,
ChartModule.forRoot(require('highcharts')),
```

3- My home.component.ts file looks like this:
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
selector: 'jhi-home',
  template: '<chart [options]="options"></chart>'
})

export class HomeComponent {
constructor() {
this.options = {
  title: { text: 'simple chart' },
  series: [{
    data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2],
  }]
};
}
options: Object; 
}
```

It gives me the following error

```
Promise rejection: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'options' since it isn't a known property of 'chart'. ("<chart [ERROR ->][options]="options"></chart>"): HomeComponent@0:7
'chart' is not a known element:
1. If 'chart' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'chart' is a Web Component then add "CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA" to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message. ("[ERROR ->]<chart [options]="options"></chart>"): HomeComponent@0:0 ; Zone: <root> ; Task: Promise.then ;
```

Can somebody help me.

Comment: Have you looked at the example about leaflet in your generated README.md?  You may try to check whether highcharts.js is included into your bundle. I haven't tried highcharts but I think you need to add types for typescript and add import highchart.js into vendor.ts and probably some CSS too in vendor.css. otherwise  you may have angular2-highcharts but no highcharts.js

Comment: I tried to put in vendor.tx : "import 'highcharts';" import 'angular2-highcharts'; But it still gives the same error.

Comment: Have you checked that highcharts functions have been included in your bundle? The path in vendor.ts imports should match what's in your node_modules folder so maybe "import 'highcharts/highcharts.js';"

Comment: Inside node_modules I have the highchart folder with the file highchart.js.. But still adding "import 'highcharts/highcharts.js'; in vendor.ts. I still have the same problem. :(